# Why's my Laravel website throwing CORS error while deployed on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Just to preface: the website works as intended while running it on localhost

I've deployed my Laravel website to Elastic Beanstalk and I've configured the EC2 instance accordingly as well populated RDS with sufficient data.

The endpoints that live in the `api.php` file that are being called on the React.js frontend are all hard coded.  For example, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login`.

I did the obvious:

- replaced the endpoint URL with the new Elastic Beanstalk URL.  I.e. -
  `http://myapp.something.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/login`.
- On the server while ssh'd in, I also changed the `.env` file's value of
  `APP_URL` to http://myapp.something.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

But despite doing these, I get a CORS issue.  It looks like the website is still somehow pointing to localhost.

How can I make it so that the website talks to the new Elastic Beanstalk URL hits the endpoints correctly?

Comment: Exactly what is the _"CORS issue"_ or error that you're getting? When you say you _"replaced the endpoint URL"_, what does that mean? Also, changing an `.env` file value only applies during your app's build and typically, they need to start with `REACT_APP` or `VITE_APP` depending on your build system

Comment: You need to support CORS by adding the proper headers like `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` etc. into your laravel application.